# How to use Async views and urls in Django?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-requests, aiohttp

I build an application using django that can get data from an api. At first, I used the python requests to connect to the api and it's working. But the problem is I find it a little bit slow when it comes to the web page loading speed.
So i decided to use async function in my codes, but i keep getting an error .

Here's my codes:

**views.py**

```
async def e_sign_page(request):
    start_time = time.time()
    template_name = "e_sign/e_sign_table.html"

    url = f"API_URL_HERE"

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        esign = []
        doc = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(session, url))
        esign.append(doc)
        docs = await asyncio.gather(*esign)
    end_time = time.time()
    total = end_time - start_time
    print("Code Execution Time : ", total)
    context = {
        'docs' : docs
    }

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from e_sign.resources.e_sign import (
    e_sign_page,

)


urlpatterns = [
    path("e-sign-page/", e_sign_page, name = "e_sign_page"),

]
```

**utils.py**

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        return await resp.json()
```

**Here's my errors that I'm receiving**
['coroutine' object has no attribute 'get'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD1Ib.png)

How to fix this?

Comment: Seems to be a known issue with old versions of aiohttp. I can't reproduce your error. Can you check your version? Mine is 3.7.3